Refutation of Protestant denial of the priestly ability to forgive sins?
Catholics and some Protestants believe that priests/pastors can forgive sin, usually citing John 20:23 as justification. For example, one variant of the Anglican liturgy has the Pastor make the following pronouncement:

By the authority of Christ given to the Church I absolve you from your sins

Another, similar form:

By [Christ's] authority committed to me, I absolve you from all your sins

Other Protestants believe that John 20:23 only applied to the original Apostles and would apparently object to the above. (I should note that my understanding is that Protestants, and perhaps even Roman Catholics, do agree that pastors/priests aren't themselves able to absolve sin, but merely serve as "intermediaries" of Christ to do so. Indeed, the specifics of the above clearly call this out.)
Now, this discussion is usually entangled with the Roman Catholic belief in the Apostolic Succession. However, as I understand it, all Protestants reject the Succession.
On what grounds, therefore, do (some) Protestants accept John 20:23 as applying to all called and ordained ministers? (In other words, what do those Protestants who side with Roman Catholics on the matter of the priestly/pastoral ability to deliver or withhold forgiveness respond to those who deny such ability?)
Related reading:

According to Arminian Protestants, who can forgive sin or withhold forgiveness?
What is the Protestant view of John 20:23 and the disciples ability to forgive sins?
Does the priest have the power to forgive sins?
Does John 20:23 mean that Catholic priests can forgive sins?


Many protestants don't reject apostolic succession, just the Catholic teachings on it, including Anglicans, Lutherans, and possibly Presbyterians (they don't talk about it, but have the same basic claim as the Anglicans). Possibly more. But on the other hand, probably most Protestants would say that even the Apostles never actually had the power to forgive sins, just to proclaim the forgiveness of sins.

That's two different questions. Are you asking for a "Refutation of Protestant denial", or for why "Protestants accept"?

@RayButterworth, both. You're perhaps missing that "Protestants" in those refer to different groups. Group A (Calvinists?) denies that priests/pastors can pronounce or withhold forgiveness. Group B (A/L/P?) disagrees. Therefore, B presumably has a refutation of A's position, i.e. an explanation why they accept it despite B's disagreement.

@curiousdannii, I think Protestants agree that the pronunciation of absolution doesn't mean that humans can forgive sin, but rather, that humans are authorized to act in the stead of Christ to forgive sin, which certainly seems consistent with John 20:23. I'd accept that my understanding of the Protestant (at least in A/L and maybe P sects) take on AS is wrong, but that smells suspiciously like an Answer. Care to post one?

John 20:23 is not regarding forgiveness of sin from God.  It is regarding forgiving others.  A blood sacrifice is required for forgiveness of sin from God:
Hebrews 9:22

And almost all things are by the law purged with blood; and without shedding of blood is no remission.

God forgave the world of its sins through the shed blood of Jesus Christ:
2 Corinthians 5:18-21

And all things are of God, who hath reconciled us to himself by Jesus Christ, and hath given to us the ministry of reconciliation;
19 To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation.
20 Now then we are ambassadors for Christ, as though God did beseech you by us: we pray you in Christ's stead, be ye reconciled to God.
21 For he hath made him to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him.

Ephesians 1:7

In whom we have redemption through his blood, the forgiveness of sins, according to the riches of his grace;

Colossians 1:14

In whom we have redemption through his blood, even the forgiveness of sins:

Peter, James, John (the twelve) are trying to convince Israel of who Jesus Christ was (their Messiah).  This is so they will receive their promised earthly kingdom of heaven and be forgiven of their post-cross sins at their "times of refreshing from the presence of the Lord".
Acts 3:12-21

And when Peter saw it, he answered unto the people, Ye men of Israel, why marvel ye at this? or why look ye so earnestly on us, as though by our own power or holiness we had made this man to walk?
13 The God of Abraham, and of Isaac, and of Jacob, the God of our fathers, hath glorified his Son Jesus; whom ye delivered up, and denied him in the presence of Pilate, when he was determined to let him go.
14 But ye denied the Holy One and the Just, and desired a murderer to be granted unto you;
15 And killed the Prince of life, whom God hath raised from the dead; whereof we are witnesses.
16 And his name through faith in his name hath made this man strong, whom ye see and know: yea, the faith which is by him hath given him this perfect soundness in the presence of you all.
17 And now, brethren, I wot that through ignorance ye did it, as did also your rulers.
18 But those things, which God before had shewed by the mouth of all his prophets, that Christ should suffer, he hath so fulfilled.
19 Repent ye therefore, and be converted, that your sins may be blotted out, when the times of refreshing shall come from the presence of the Lord.
20 And he shall send Jesus Christ, which before was preached unto you:
21 Whom the heaven must receive until the times of restitution of all things, which God hath spoken by the mouth of all his holy prophets since the world began.

Fortunately for us, through Israel's fall, salvation has come freely to all who will believe and without having to wait on Israel's "times of refreshing".
Romans 11:11

I say then, Have they stumbled that they should fall? God forbid: but rather through their fall salvation is come unto the Gentiles, for to provoke them to jealousy.

Romans 3:23-26

For all have sinned, and come short of the glory of God;
24 Being justified freely by his grace through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus:
25 Whom God hath set forth to be a propitiation through faith in his blood, to declare his righteousness for the remission of sins that are past, through the forbearance of God;
26 To declare, I say, at this time his righteousness: that he might be just, and the justifier of him which believeth in Jesus.


I don't see how this answers the Question? Roman Catholics and some Protestants believe priests/pastors are able to — not "forgive" sin, precisely, since Christ already accomplished that — act as delivery vessels for already-accomplished forgiveness of sin. RC rationalizes this through the Apostolic Succession. Some Protestants deny that this is possible. How do Protestants that side with RC (and who typically cite John 20:23 as the basis), but do not have the AS, justify this?

@Matthew Apologies!  I misunderstood the question.
